# Using screen in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I'm running a game server on a remote server where I use a detached screen instance to leave it running.
I'm now creating a script that can be used to shut down the server, back up all the vital files and start it up again, however I'm having a few difficulties with dealing with the screen.

I assumed that I could just switch into the detached screen in the script (after the server had already been shut down) by calling screen -r in the script.
But that doesn't seem to work because if I run the script from outside screen it just launches the server in that session.

```
screen -r
cd ~/servers/StarMade/
sh StarMade-dedicated-server-linux.sh
screen -d
```

This is what I thought would do the trick but it doesn't. Maybe somebody can help me out here. I'm not a bash expert. In fact this is propably my first bash script that doesn't include "Hello World". Thanks.

Comment: Just take into account "Supervisor", the right tool for your needs

Comment: Might be a bit overkill for the ONE script that I want to run. But if my needs become more complex I'll be sure to check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script, as in your example, will get executed by your sell, not the one in the screen. You need to tell the running screen to read a file and execute it - that's what the -X option is for.

Try

```
tempfile=$(mktemp)
cat > $tempfile <<EOF
cd ~/servers/StarMade/
sh StarMade-dedicated-server-linux.sh
EOF
screen -X readbuf $tempfile
screen -X paste .
rm -f $tempfile
```

You can leave screen running in a 2nd terminal session to see what happens.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. A few questions. First, what is that EOF thing you're doing there? And secondly screen -X attaches a command to a running screen session, right? Don't I need to specify which one? Lastly when I'm done with this, what do I need to change in my script? Or from where do I run it now?

Comment: The EOF thing is a *here document*, which means everything between the <<EOF and the EOF will be put into the standard input of `cat`, which writes it to the temp file. Second, -X will select the same screen that -r does - but you can combine -X with -r to select a specific one. Third, you replace your complete script with mine, and run it on the computer where screen is running.